# UITableView calling didEndDisplayingCell incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am having an issue using a `UITableView`'s `didEndDisplayingCell` method. I am using this method along with `willDisplayCell` to handle some extra data tracking for my table. The problem is that `didEndDisplayingCell` is being called several times in a row, and at times where the cell is actually still being displayed. I cannot figure out why this would happen.

**More Details**

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController to provide data for the table. Changes come into the table from an `NSManagedObjectContext` on a different queue and then get merged into the `NSManagedObjectContext` that the table uses. This all seems to be working fine. Looking at my implementation of the above methods:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    debugPrint("willDisplay cell at \(indexPath).")
    self.dataProvider.addTrackedRelatedRecords(for: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    debugPrint("didEndDisplaying cell at \(indexPath).")
    self.dataProvider.removeTrackedRelatedRecords(for: indexPath)
}
```

The output I'm seeing here is:

```
 "Updating rows in table at [0, 0]". <=== This is an update to the data
 "willDisplay cell at [0, 0]."       <=== This is what I expect
 "didEndDisplaying cell at [0, 0]"
 "didEndDisplaying cell at [0, 0]"
 "didEndDisplaying cell at [0, 0]"
```

The cell remains visible in the table and never disappears. There is nothing that I can see that would cause the `didEndDisplaying` to be called, especially repeatedly.

I can work around this issue by checking to see if the cell is actually still visible, by adding the following to the `didEndDisplayingCell` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    debugPrint("didEndDisplaying cell at \(indexPath).")
    // WORK AROUND
    if let visibleRows = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows, visibleRows.contains(indexPath) {
        return
    }
    self.dataProvider.removeTrackedRelatedRecords(for: indexPath)
}
```

This correctly sees that the cell is still visible, so won't remove my extra tracking. But, if the cell is visible, why is the method being called at all?

Obviously there is a lot of other code at work in my app. I will attempt to cull this down to a very simple case, but thought I'd post this first to see if anyone has seen cases where this might happen. That might help me track it down.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Can you identify this as happening in a specific version of iOS?

Comment: @holly, good question. I will try the same on iOS 9.3 and see what I get.

Comment: @holly, I just tried this on iOS 9.3.5 and have the same result. The original test was on iOS 10.3.1.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue and I'm posting an answer in case anyone else sees this issue and would be helped by what I found.

It turns out that I had inadvertently left a `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)` inside a `tableView.beginUpdates()` and  `tableView.endUpdates()` block.

I believe that the `reloadRows` was causing the cell to be replaced, which would cause a `didEndDisplayingCell`. And, since there were a couple updates happening inside the block, these were being queued up and posted once the `tableView.endUpdates()` was called.

Removing the `reloadRows` call fixed the issue and all is working as expected.

Comment: If I remove "reloadRows" so how can I update these rows??

Comment: I am re-configuring the cell (instead of reloading) when NSFetchedResultsChangeType is .update and I get didEndDisplaying called multiple times for the first cell (which is newly added) while it is still visible. In other words, I do a pull-to-refresh, it calls .insert and .update, the new result appears on IndexPath 0,0 and didEndDisplaying is called for IndexPath 0,0. That is pausing the download for the media content that is supposed to be displayed by the cell.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I was calling `reloadData()` whenever I was changing the `centeredIndexPath`. Make sure you are not reloading the data as all the cells will call `didEndDisplaying` (as you are reloading it).